# How to send Html code in Json and render with data table

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

Here is the code trying to render a html code dynamically using JSON and Data Table
code trying to render `<span class='axis-download'>fff</span>`

```
document.body.appendChild(buildHtmlTable([
    {"name" : "abc", "age" : 50},
    {"age" : "25", "hobby" : "<span class=\'axis-download\'>fff</span>"},
    {"name" : "xyz", "hobby" : "programming"}
]));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7MRx6/338/

Answer (score 0):

Basically, instead of appending a child text node, you need to set the inner HTML of your TD.

Changed

```
td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i][columns[j]] || ''));
```

to

```
td.innerHTML = arr[i][columns[j]] || '';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1urzrapp/